# Perl printf Spacing

Tags: perl, printf

I'm using printf to print out data in 2 columns. The first column is max 12 characters, but the data in the second column can get quite long. Is there a way to make it start from the same indentation that it starts on the first line after it line-wraps?

```
printf("%-12s\t%s", $key, $result);
```

Comment: Can you show some sample input and output?

Comment: Printf can't do that.  You need to break `$result` up into 60-character blocks, put it together with the key, some newlines, and some 12-space-plus-a-tab character strings, then print that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use the core library [`Text::Wrap`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Wrap.html).

The following would implement what you're talking about:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Wrap;

local $Text::Wrap::columns = 72;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($word, $paragraph) = split ' ', $_, 2;
    print wrap(sprintf("%-12s", $word), ' 'x12, $paragraph), "\n";
}

__DATA__
one The fallen python hurts behind your entering delight.  A leader defects within the birth!  The torture overflows?  The verdict beams behind the energy.
two A convinced undergraduate seasons the bonus.  The present alert mends inside the gesture.  How will the publicized coordinate swallow a log panic?
three A tourist faints?  An alive biography behaves on top of a grief.  A storm scares a conductor throughout an anxious initiate.
```

Outputs:

```
one         The fallen python hurts behind your entering delight.  A
            leader defects within the birth!  The torture overflows?
            The verdict beams behind the energy.

two         A convinced undergraduate seasons the bonus.  The present
            alert mends inside the gesture.  How will the publicized
            coordinate swallow a log panic?

three       A tourist faints?  An alive biography behaves on top of a
            grief.  A storm scares a conductor throughout an anxious
            initiate.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think printf can do what you want by itself, but you can do the wrapping yourself. The following example is primitive but usable:

```
sub wrap {
    my ($str, $first_col_size, $max_col_size) = @_;
    my $ret = $str;
    $ret =~ s/(.{$max_col_size})/"$1\n" . (' ' x $first_col_size) . "\t"/ge;
    $ret;
}

printf("%-12s\t%s\n", $key, wrap($result, 12, 60));
```

Or maybe you could use something like [Text::ASCIITable on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ASCIITable) to do what you need.